# What would cause @microsoft/signalr disconnection when returning a null response from an invoke method call?

Tags: asp.net-core, null, signalr

While using AspNetCore Hub (3.1.0.0), I have a method that returns an object.  In some situations, I want to return null.  This seems valid.

When the client performs an invoke and a valid string is returned, it works as expected.  However, if the method returns null, the connection is disconnected with a generic error "Error: Invocation canceled due to the underlying connection being closed."

I first saw this on methods that return Entity Framework objects but I am seeing it on methods that return String as well.

On server (abbreviated):

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public String TestString()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }

    public String TestNull()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

On client:

```
let myConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .withUrl("MyHub")
                    .withAutomaticReconnect()
                    .build();

myConnection.start();  

myConnection.invoke('TestString').then( x => console.log(x) );   // works fine.

myConnection.invoke('TestNull').then( x => console.log(x) );     // disconnects.
```

I could understand if the error was something about not being able to parse the null response or something.  But the connection dying with "Error: Invocation canceled due to the underlying connection being closed." does not seem right.

Any ideas?

I know I can catch the exception and that the withAutomaticReconnect correctly reconnects..  but a null return seems valid and I'd like to get it working that way.

Thanks.

Comment: Turn on server side logging. Also, do you happen to be using netcoreapp3.1 with system.text.json 5.0?

Comment: Same case for me. I am using aspnetcore3.1

Comment: Similar thing here, however I'm not actually returning null from server. DTO is IEnumerable<MyClass> and I return a single valid MyClass instance however on the client I get a null, and then connection closes.

Comment: I've solved the issue in my case. It seems the net5.0 SignalR library does not return values with `InvokeAsync` - the return is ALWAYS null. However if the invoked procedure is registered in the client (`connection.On("<procedure>", () => { ... });` then that procedure is invoked with the server-sent data. 

I don't think this is the intended behavior for `InvokeAsync`, because there is the existing method of `SendAsync` which does that specifically per the MS docs.